# Run a SQL Server trigger when new data is added to the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, gis

I want to be able to create a trigger that runs when new data is added to my table. I have a trigger that creates a geography column from lat long, I would like the below script to run when ever new data is added to the database.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
    ADD geographyColumn AS geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Long) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), Lat) + ')', 4326)
```

Comment: The script in your question adds a computed column to a table. That need only be done once. The geography value will be calculated automatically when data are retrieved so there is no need for a trigger. If that is not occurring as expected, add details about the problem to your question with your `CREATE TABLE` DDL.

Comment: Are you thinking of a default? That would give you a default value if it wasn't supplied. If you want to have supplied values changed, I think you will need to use triggers

Comment: I think you don't understand the difference between a [DML Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/dml-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) and a [Computed Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017) is. They are very different things/objects.

Comment: Thank @Larnu that is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pseudo-code for a trigger

```
create trigger <trigger name>
on <your table>
for insert
as
update <your table>
set geographyColumn = <here you have to calculate the new datum>
where inserted.key = <your table>.key --join inserted and your table on key attributes so you update only for freshly added rows
```

Note: on SQL Server triggers are 'after triggers' so you already have new data inside your table.